# ApiController GET Action naming

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I have an ApiController with multiple GET Actions. The problem is that I want to name my actions without "Get" in the start of their names.

For instance, I can have an Action named `GetImage` and it will work just fine.
If I will name it `UpdateImage` it wont call the Action, because it probably want an explicit "Get" in the start of the action name.

I can solve it by defining different route for each action I want to use, but I am sure there must be an easier way achieving it.

I also tried [HttpGet] attribute and unfortunately it didn't do the trick.

**My Route Config:**

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ImagesApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/images/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "ImageStorageManager",id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and I am accessing it by `api/images/GetImage` or `api/images/UpdateImage`

Comment: I'm assuming you're not actually planning to make a `PUT` request, via a `GET` for update?

Answer (score 6):

The way I've been creating api controller that aren't just for a single object might help you.  I got the approach from John Papa's SPA talk on PluralSight (I highly recommend that for learning single page applications).  He also walks through this in one of the modules.

It has 2 parts.

Part 1, setting up the routes to do the 2 normal scenarios and then added a 3rd for what i want:

```
// ex: api/persons
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerOnly,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );// ex: api/sessionbriefs

//  ex: api/persons/1
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAndId,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: null, //defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } //,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be all digits
        );

// ex: api/lookups/all
// ex: api/lookups/rooms
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAction,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Part 2, in the lookups controler (in John Papa's case), add an ActionName attribute to the methods:

```
    // GET: api/lookups/rooms
    [ActionName("rooms")]
    public IEnumerable<Room> GetRooms()
    {
        return Uow.Rooms.GetAll().OrderBy(r => r.Name);
    }

    // GET: api/lookups/timeslots
    [ActionName("timeslots")]
    public IEnumerable<TimeSlot> GetTimeSlots()
    {
        return Uow.TimeSlots.GetAll().OrderBy(ts => ts.Start);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately id didn't do the trick. 

I am doing it with "hard coded" route mapping, since I didn't found any other ways that will make it work other than that.

Answer (score 2):

Decorate your action with [HttpGet]. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api for details on why, and how ApiController routing works.

Comment: And from there the link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection provides even greater detail, especially related to the nitty-gritty of action selection based on parameters.

Answer (score 0):

in .net core - you can do the following in your ImagesController to map actions ad-hoc:

```
// api/images/{id}
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(string id) { ... }

// api/images/myaction/{id}
[HttpGet("myaction/{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> GetMyAction(string id) { ... }
```